# HTML input range slider call function when stop sliding

Tags: html, slider

I have a slider implemented in HTML:

```
<input type="range" onchange="app.setSpeed()" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="255" />
```

It incrementally calls my function `app.setSpeed()`. But how can I 
call the function just at the release of the slider? I saw there should exist something like on-handle-up, but that does not work in my HTML version.

Comment: In case you're still around, please give more details: what plugin is this exactly, to start with.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with jQuery `.click()` or `.change()` functions:

```js
$('#range').change(function() {
  $('div').html( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="range">
<div></div>
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjq0k8uq/)

---

You can also do it with pure **JavaScript*:

```js
function addEvent(el, name, func, bool) {
 if (el.addEventListener) el.addEventListener(name, func, bool);
 else if (el.attachEvent) el.attachEvent('on' + name, dunc);
 else el['on' + name] = func;
}
addEvent(range, 'change', function(e) {
 myText.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range">
<div id="myText"></div>
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjq0k8uq/1/)

---

Hope that helped.

Comment: But what if you slide the range slider to the value that it was when you started sliding? It doesn't trigger change

Answer (score -2):

You can use [jQuery range slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) because it provides such functionality.